# Tomcat 6.0.36 not reporting why it responded with 400

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a tomcat server and java client with java.net.HttpUrlConnection sending messages. Usually all works fine, but there some requests the client sends out which are responded with a 400 http error.

The problem is that nothing is shown on tomcat logs. I even tried to put .level=fine and other log level changes, and still no exception or error was shown.

I'm suspecting bad encoding in request or something like that, but tomcat doesn't give me any clues.

By the way, the URL is OK. I also see the request reaches the server but not to my servlet.
It appears tomcat gets the message, declares it bad and doesn't log what's wrong.

Can anybody think of a way to see the 400 reason?
Thank you

Comment: What log files did you look at? Do you have a Web server like Apache in front on Tomcat?

Comment: No. I don't. I looked at Catalina.out, localhost...

Comment: Tell us more about your logging mechanism. Also tell us which kind of application are you using? Spring/plain servlet ... ??

Comment: Plain servlet. I see in debug time that the server doesn't get the message. Tomcat blocks it.

Comment: What is in the response body when you get the 400 status code?

Comment: Show us the server and client code.

Comment: Henry, There is no response body - an exception is thrown by the HttpUrlClient.

Comment: By what I am seeing, if I truncate a specific httpheader's value, it passes - I am thinking it is a size limitation, but I increased maxHttpHeaderSize and maxPostSize and it didn't help :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally figured out -
I saw that the size of the total headers + size of data written to OutputStream - was exceptionally high - and so I defined in the Tomcat HTTP connector:

Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP 1/1" **maxPostSize="10485760" maxHttpHeaderSize="10485760"**/

It is a shame Tomcat doesn't just tell me this, and I had to guess my - I will report this as a bug.

Thank you

Comment: it would be nice if you could also link that bug here when you have reported it, as I would suspect people find here through googling

Comment: usefull info faced the same issue took a week to fix the same.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this was also the solution to the "http 400 bad request" error on Internet Explorer 11.
Adding

```
maxHttpHeaderSize="10485760" maxPostSize="10485760"
```

to the Connector-node of Tomcat's server.xml.

Seems my ajax-request (extjs) on IE11 are using a bigger request header then the default (8192 = 8 KB) max http header size on Tomcat 6?

With IE10 and Chrome I didn't experience this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very nice issue to be discussed about. I also faced the same issue in my organization's work. I was clueless about it as there were no good logging about it in catalina.out or in our application logs. Http calls made from client apps to the API that was running in Tomcat_8 were getting rejected by the server with 400 bad request. Only Tomcat locahost_access logs records it by printing the 400 http status fro the request. After I increased the http header size the issue got resolved.